# contrast in confocal microscopy

Tags: visible-light, microscopy, imaging

I observed fixed cells from mice tissue, thanks to confocal microscopy monochromatic 488nm. (without fluorescence staining)

In some slices, cells appear in black, and in other slices in white (surrounding tissue appear in grey).

I had a suspicion of complex phenomena due to the topology of the tissue but I can't find a clear physical explanation. If someone has some clue...?

**EDIT**

Samples are mice brain slices of 500µm.

confocal microscopy:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a picture of your observation?

Comment: @IamAStudent, I would like to, but I'm student and my advisor (a biologist), do not allow me to share pictures....

Comment: Okay, then maybe an illustration of the setup would be helpful.

Comment: So if I understood your question correctly, are you saying that the contrast seems to vary as you scan along different focal planes?

Comment: @IamAStudent, no, it from one sample to another, I have a samples of slice brain in piece of 500 micrometer, but the contrast is 'almost' the same along focal plane for the same sample